# Android Get BT device ID (or name) without waiting for event

Tags: android, bluetooth

I know how to get the BT connection events, but how do I know what BT connected device I have when my app / service starts ? the event was already been sent, so I missed it,

sample code will be great since I'm just starting to learn to develop for Android.

thanks